# Can't create User, getting "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I have some serious problem with understanding what is wrong in my code after implemented "has_secure_password" .
My issue to use "has_secure_password" and create new User.

I am using rails 4

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

2.2.3 :034 >   user=User.new(name: "user2", email: "user2@mail.com", password: "1qaz!QAZ", password_confirmation: "1qaz!QAZ")
 => # 
2.2.3 :035 > user.save!
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'user2@mail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank

**My User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_token
  has_secure_password

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  before_save { email.downcase! }

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

please help me to understand what is wrong in my code.

Comment: My Database is empty. 2.2.3 :037 >   User.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
 => 0

Comment: if I am removing "has_secure_password" from my User model then I can successfully create User.